# How to use data from scenario one into another using Cucumber and RestAssured

Tags: automation, cucumber, rest-assured

I am doing API automation using Cucumber and RestAssured.

I have a feature file having 2 scenarios.
On successful execution of Scenario 1 cookies are getting generated. I want to use these cookies as authorization is scenario 2. Can some 1 suggest me a way to do so?

Here is my Feature File look like :

```
Scenario1: Verify SignUp with Valid Email Address
    Given SignUp Payload with Email "New"
    When User Calls SignUp API with PUT request
    Then API call is success with status code 200
    And "status.status_type" in response body as "true"
    And "status.status_message" in response body as "Request Successful"
    And "item.has_signup" in response body as "true"

Scenario2: Verify SignUp for already signedUp user
    Given SignUp Payload with Email "New1"
    When User Calls SignUp API with PUT request
    Then API call is success with status code 200
    And "status.status_type" in response body as "false"
    And "status.status_message" in response body as "Looks, like you have used different email address before. Please login with original email address you used to create an account."
```

Here is how my test File look Like :

```
public class signUp {

ResponseSpecification response_spec;
RequestSpecification request;
Response response;
TestData data = new TestData();
String ia_uid_cookie;
String ia_jwt_cookie;   

@Given("SignUp Payload with Email {string}")
public void signup_Payload_with_Email(String userEmail) throws IOException{

    response_spec = new ResponseSpecBuilder().expectStatusCode(200).expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();    
    if(userEmail.equals("New")  ){
        request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpecs()).body(data.signUpPayload());
        }
    else if (userEmail.equals("New1")) {
        request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpecs()).cookies("_ia_jwt", ia_jwt_cookie, "_ia_uid", ia_uid_cookie).body(data.signUpPayload());
    }
    else{
        request = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpecs()).body(data.emptyPayload());
    }
}

@When("User Calls SignUp API with PUT request")
public void user_Calls_SignUp_API_with_PUT_request() throws IOException {
    response = request.when().put(getGlobalValue("signup_uri")).then()
               .spec(response_spec).extract().response();
        Map<String, String> userCookies = response.getCookies();
        ia_uid_cookie= userCookies.get("_ia_uid");
        ia_jwt_cookie= userCookies.get("_ia_jwt");
        }   

@Then("API call is success with status code {int}")
public void api_call_is_success_with_status_code(Integer int1) {
    assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(),200);
}

@Then("{string} in response body as {string}")
public void in_response_body_as(String actual, String expected) {
    JsonPath resp_string = responseInString(response);
    assertEquals(resp_string.get(actual).toString(), expected);
}

}
```

Comment: please tidy your question so we can read your scenarios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass test data from one test case to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504834/pass-test-data-from-one-test-case-to-another)

Comment: @lauda thnx....data providers worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dependency injection using any DI containers

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/share-data-between-steps-in-cucumber-using-scenario-context/